# How to make web service methods return string value in lines format?

Tags: c#, web-services

How to make web service methods return string value in lines format?

My web service method looks like this

```
[WebMethod]
public string GetSomeLines()
{
  System.Text.StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
  builder.AppendLine("Line1.");
  builder.AppendLine("Line2.");
  builder.AppendLine("Line3.");
  return builder.ToString();
}
```

But when I get the result from web browser or from delphi/c# consumer it will be like this:

```
Line1. Line2. Line3.
```

While I expect to see:

```
Line1.
Line2.
Line3.
```

I know may be returning a StringBuilder or String Array is an option here but I want to know if there is a way to make this with string result.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AppendLine method of StringBuilder adds default line terminator to the end of appended string. The default line terminator is the current value of the `Environment.NewLine` property, which is "\r\n" for non-Unix platforms, or "\n" for Unix platforms. So what your WebMethod is trying to return looks so:

> "Line1.\r\nLine2.\r\nLine3.\r\n".

However, the return value is serialized according to SOAP specifications by truncating "\r", and the result looks slightly different:

> "Line1.\nLine2.\nLine3.\n".

If service consumer is running on a Windows platform it would probably ignore the single "\n" character as a garbage. Probable solutions:

1. Encode return value into another format, e.g. into a byte array so: 
   `return builder.ToString().ToCharArray();`
2. Replace NewLine with another string that may be provided by the caller, e.g. into a BR tag: 
   `return builder.Replace(Environment.NewLine, "<br/>").ToString();`
3. Return array of lines or any other container with all lines separated.

Comment: Thanks SlavaGu, yes that is exactly what is happen here, thanks for your good explanation. I think there is no way to do this with “ready to use” string result. I have to use different/modified line break. But I’ll accept this answer.  Thanks :-)

Answer (score 1):

you can add the '\r\n' character at the end of each append:

builder.Append("Line1.\r\n");

or like you said: appendLine

builder.AppendLine("Line1.");

and after that, depending on your consumer ,
 you can replace the '\r\n' with a different new line string.
For browser

`<br/>` tag.

Answer (score 0):

use environement.newline while appending.